# Ruby: passing blocks as parameters from oustide class

Tags: ruby, ruby-block

I am getting below error when executing code:

```
example.rb:9:in `<main>': undefined method `each' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Line 9 is second last line in my code.

My code:

```
class TargetProvider
  def each(target,&block)
    block.call(target)
  end   
end

tp = TargetProvider.new
each { puts "Hello!" }
tp.each(1, each)
```

My motive is to call block with target parameter.

How can I pass a block outside class. Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is yout code:

```
class TargetProvider
  def each(target,&block)
    block.call(target)
  end   
end

tp = TargetProvider.new
each { puts "Hello!" } # this line is trying to run a method called each
tp.each(1, each)
```

You need to define a lambda or a proc and store it in a variable, or use the implicit block of the each.
Here is an example using a lambda:

```
class TargetProvider
  def each(target,&block)
    block.call(target)
  end   
end

tp = TargetProvider.new
each_block = lambda { |a| puts "Hello!" }
tp.each(1, &each_block)
```

Here is an example using the implicit block:

```
class TargetProvider
  def each(target,&block)
    block.call(target)
  end   
end

tp = TargetProvider.new
each_block = lambda { |a| puts "Hello!" }
tp.each(1) { puts "Hello!" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is here:

```
tp = TargetProvider.new
each { puts "Hello!" } # Here
tp.each(1, each)
```

Here, you are *calling* `each` method, not declaring a new variable.
In Ruby, if you call a method without specifying its object (via `object.method`), interpreter searches for that method in `MainObject`.

It's clear that there no such method in it, so that's what an error is about.

What you may want to achieve is looks like this:

```
tp = TargetProvider.new
tp.each(1) { puts "Hello!" }
```

That code calls `TargetProvider`'s `each` method passing it a block.

Comment: "In Ruby, if you call a method without specifying its object (via `object.method`), interpreter searches for that method in `MainObject`." – No. The implicit receiver is `self`, not `MainObject` (whatever that is.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag
And what is `self` outside any class, in top-level context? Right it's `main` object, check it out in irb.